# Executing AOP using meld.js(cujojs) for standalone javascript functions is not working

Tags: javascript, auditing, cujojs

When I try to implement AOP using meld.js (from cujojs) for standalone javascript functions, it is NOT executing Advice. I have been trying with the below code.

```
var meld = require("meld")

function afterReturn(returnValue){
       console.log(returnValue);
}

function test(x,y) {
      console.log(x);
      console.log(y);
      return x+y;
}

var remover = meld.afterReturning(test, afterReturn);
```

`test(5,6);`:

> 5 AND 6

But, when I wrap the function inside some object (myo), it works.
I don't want to wrap functions inside any object.

```
var meld = require("meld")

function x(returnValue) {
    console.log(returnValue);
}

var myo = {
   test : function(x,y) {
      console.log(x);
      console.log(y);
      return x+y;
   }
}

var remover = meld.afterReturning(myo,'test', x);
```

`myo.test(5,6);`:

> 5, 6 AND 11

Could you please correct me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript functions are sacred and can never be tampered with externally. When passing a function directly, instead of an object with a method, the returned value is the advised function.

Take a look at the second code sample for afterReturning https://github.com/cujojs/meld/blob/master/docs/api.md#meldafterreturning

`var advisedFunction = meld.afterReturning(functionToAdvise, afterReturningFunction);`

Comment: Great @scothis . I some how missed reading this part from documentation.Thanks for the link. working now.